# A powerful drink

Tags: story, number-sequence

I'm addicted to this stuff.

I had my first double when I was 16.  There were five of us that night on the town.  I didn't think much of it then, but two years later I had another double, and then another the following year.

That was when I first realized I might have a problem.  I cut it off cold-turkey for the next 3 years, but then it came back with a vengeance.  I had a double, then the next year I had a *triple*.  The year after that I had three doubles in a row!

I slowed down a bit after that; only one double a year for the next two years, and then a long dry spell.  I only cheated once until I was 38.

Then I fell hard.  I had two doubles that year, followed by a double and a triple the next year, then *two* doubles and a triple.  I just had my first quadruple, and I don't know *what* I'm going to have next year.

***Do you?***

Comment: Unclear: "a triple the next year, then two doubles and a triple". The "two doubles and a triple" refer to the same year? or the year after?

Comment: @fffred: The double and triple were one year, and the two doubles and a triple were another year.

Comment: THIS is a good example of a number sequence puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi - Thanks - I was afraid I might be giving away too much just by using that tag, but it was a choice between that and "math", and that arguably gives away *more*.  Wasn't aware that "number-sequence" puzzles had such a bad reputation...

Comment: Yeah, most puzzles under [number-sequence] are something like "13, 21, 34, what comes next?" - nearly always very low quality. This one's really good though!

Comment: I have several dubbels, tripels, and quads a week.. If this guy thinks he has a problem having one a year, I think I need to talk to someone

Comment: @QuestionMarks - Admittedly, the analogy doesn't work 100%, but why let that get in the way of a good story puzzle?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Next year you're going to have:

> a triple.

The references are to:

> groups of repeated digits in the number 2^Y, where Y is the year number.  Here's a table of results:
>
>  16 -> 2^16 = 6**55**36
>  17 -> 2^17 = 131072
>  18 -> 2^18 = 2621**44**
>  19 -> 2^19 = 5242**88**
>  20 -> 2^20 = 1048576
>  21 -> 2^21 = 2097152
>  22 -> 2^22 = 4194304
>  23 -> 2^23 = 83**88**608
>  24 -> 2^24 = 16**777**216
>  25 -> 2^25 = **335544**32
>  26 -> 2^26 = 6710**88**64
>  27 -> 2^27 = 13421**77**28
>  28 -> 2^28 = 268435456
>  29 -> 2^29 = 536870912
>  30 -> 2^30 = 1073741824
>  31 -> 2^31 = 2147483648
>  32 -> 2^32 = 4294967296
>  33 -> 2^33 = 858**99**34592
>  34 -> 2^34 = 17179869184
>  35 -> 2^35 = 34359738368
>  36 -> 2^36 = 68719476736
>  37 -> 2^37 = 137438953472
>  38 -> 2^38 = 2748**77**9069**44**
>  39 -> 2^39 = 5497**55**813**888**
>  40 -> 2^40 = 10**99**5**11**62**777**6
>  41 -> 2^41 = 21**99**0232**5555**2
>  42 -> 2^42 = 43980465**111**04

Comment: Ha! *Powerful*! Get it?

Comment: Nailed it.  Might be good to add some explanations of the clues, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Work in progress:**

> You will have ...

---

Here's a timeline of #s in your habit:

> * 16: first double
>  
>  5 of us that night on town
>  
>  * 18 double,
>  * 19 double
>  
>  first time realized problem
>  
>  * 20 cut off
>  * 21 cut off
>  * 22 cut off
>  * 23 double
>  * 24 triple
>  * 25 three doubles in a row
>  * 26 one double a yr
>  * 27 one double a yr
>  
>  only one cheat until age 38
>  
>  * 38 two doubles
>  * 39 double and triple
>  * 40 had two doubles & a triple
>  
>  * 41 first quadruple
>  
>  what will have next year? [42?]

The pattern I notice above is that:

> * You can fit 8 in twice once yr=16, when you had your first double
>
>  * You can fit in 8 in three times at yr=24, when you had 3 doubles, so maybe double is referring to an operation upon # 4. A 'double' is 4*2=8, 3 doubles is 8*3=24.
>  
>  Not sure what coherent pattern keeps up throughout this madness yet, however.

Comment: You're off by one on the middle section - 20, 21, and 22 have none.  It came back at 23.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @DarrelHoffman. I cleaned up the timeline